# Execute a binary file

Tags: command-line, binary

When I want to execute a binary file or program which is named as `vtmc.ubu.ifc`, I have to use the terminal to go to that bin folder where the program exists and have to execute the program by `./vtmc.ubu.ifc`.

How can I run the program without having to go to that folder, just by using the command like `vtmc.ubu.ifc`, similar to programs like `vmd`, `xmgrace` etc opens just by typing `vmd` or `xmgrace` in the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` file to add the directory where your program is located like this (note here that this is editing the `.bashrc` script which is a script executed by `bash` every time an interactive bash shell is started):

1. open a terminal
2. `gedit .bashrc`
3. go to the end of the file an add:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:"directory of the program"
   ```
4. save the file and quit gedit
5. type into your terminal: `. .bashrc` - in the future you don't need to do that; it is only to make your changes usable in the current terminal session

N.B. In order to add the program to the PATH env var of other users, edit the `/home/USERNAME/.bashrc` script of each user. And to make the program executable in a root shell make the same modification to the `/root/.bashrc` script.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods that I know to accomplish what you are up to more easily:

## 1st Method (Easiest)

Going to the place where the application is by window explorer like Nautilus (the default window explorer) and then right-click and open terminal at that location and then run the application through the terminal

## 2nd Method (Recommended)

Add the application path into environment variable or `PATH` variable.

The official way of adding a path into `$PATH` is by creating a file (called a bash file and mostly ends with .sh for distinguishing purpose only) in the `/etc/profile.d/` and in that file, update the `$PATH` by `export` command.

For example, in order to add Android Studio application path into path variable (`$PATH`), follow the steps bellow:

1. Go to `/etc/profile.d/`
2. Create a text file using nano or vim or sublime and name it "**my_android_studio.sh**"
3. Add following code block to the file **and then save the file**:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android_studio/android-studio/bin
   ANDROID_SDK=~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_SDK
   ```

That's it! From now on, you could just run the application using the application's name.